# Terraform create Cloud SQL replica alway get unkown provider error

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-sql

Here is my tf files：
https://gist.github.com/Rukeith/bd194e808adb3ecfe982a7bdda9952a4

Terraform Version：

```
Terraform v0.12.6
+ provider.google-beta v2.12.0
+ provider.random v2.2.0
```

Terraform got an error, while cloud SQL read replica finish creation complete

[image]

And if I want to update the cloud sql replica setting, I got an error below.

[image]

Second example：

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "egs" {
  provider = "google-beta"

  name           = "egs-firewall"
  network        = "default"
  enable_logging = true

  target_tags   = ["egs"]
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["8080"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Put error messages as text in your question, not as inlined images. Same for any other extra material related to your question: do not give a link to it, put was is needed in the question itself.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I had added a more simple example, it still got the error about unknown provider google

Comment: Are you sure that you even need to specify the provider in these resources? If so, maybe try adding an alias (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances for more on that)